# Combining rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to combine rows in SQL Server.

Assume I have a table like:

```
  C1 |  C2  | C3
  1  |  A   | 
  1  |      | 
  1  |      |  B
  2  |  A   |  
  2  |      |  C
```

And I want to end up with:

```
  C1 |  C2  | C3
  1  |  A   |  B
  2  |  A   |  C
```

Any way I can do this with one query?

At the moment I'm parsing the data manually with c#, but it's slow, and I can't limit the number of rows that are returned easily.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can your data rows have C2 and C3 populated in the same row?  Can a C1 value have multiple rows where when you combine the rows both C2 and C3 would have multiple values?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For your example data

```
SELECT C1,
       MAX(C2) AS C2,
       MAX(C3) AS C3
FROM   YourTable
GROUP  BY C1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb1f0/3)

Comment: Thanks! It didn't occur to me to use max on strings. Much appreciated.